# PHP works locally, not on server

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've been developing a custom CMS using Codeigniter locally and I've just gotten to the point where I need to upload it to a staging server to do some more testing.

Everything works except for the sidebar section of the site that uses a widget system. I initially thought it was just differences between PHP versions, as I am running 5.4.4 locally and the server was 5.3. After upgrading the server to 5.4.7, the sidebar is still not appearing. I get no error, just nothing displays.

This is the Widget library code:

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Widgets {

    private $_ci;
    protected $parser_enable = FALSE;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->widgets();
    }

    public function widgets(){
        $this->_ci =& get_instance();
    }

    public function build($view,$data=array()){
        $view = get_class($this).'/'.$view;
        $subdir = '';
        if (strpos($view, '/') !== FALSE)
        {
                // explode the path so we can separate the filename from the path
                $x = explode('/', $view);

                // Reset the $class variable now that we know the actual filename
                $view = end($x);

                // Kill the filename from the array
                unset($x[count($x)-1]);

                // Glue the path back together, sans filename
                $subdir = implode($x, '/').'/';
        }

        $widget_view = APPPATH.'widgets/'.$subdir.'views/'.$view.EXT;

        if(file_exists($widget_view)){
            $widget_view = '../widgets/'.$subdir.'views/'.$view.EXT;
            if($this->parser_enable){
                $this->_ci->load->library('parser');
               return $this->_ci->parser->parse($widget_view,$data,TRUE);
            }
            else{
                return $this->_ci->load->view($widget_view,$data,TRUE);
            }
        }

        return FALSE;
    }

    public function __get($var) {
        static $ci;
        isset($ci) OR $ci = get_instance();
        return $ci->$var;
    }
}
```

Does anything jump out that could cause it not to display?

Is there anything I should be looking at to make it compatible, such as server modules? What on the server could be affecting this?

EDIT:

I have the widgets residing in the following path:

```
/public_html/application/widgets/recent_news/views/view.php
```

The `$widget_view = 'widgets/'.$subdir.'views/'.$view.EXT;` variable is returning `widgets/Recent_news/views/view.php` which is getting passed to:

```
if(file_exists($widget_view)){
    return $this->_ci->load->view($widget_view,$data,TRUE);
}
```

The application path in $widget_view doesn't seem to be correct on the staging server, so file_exists() returns false and doesn't load the view (which would have an incorrect path anyways).

I just can't seem to make it read the correct path, any suggestions?

Comment: `phpinfo();` see what that gives you

Comment: The only thing I see right off is the line $widget_view = '../widgets/'. Are you sure that path is correct? You should use absolute paths instead to be sure.

Comment: @Norse what in phpinfo() besides version should I pay attention to?

Comment: @shakabra Good point, I think you're on the right track, I'll test it when I'm back from lunch

Comment: Try looking at the source code of the page in the browser. Perhaps a warning that is not visible in normal view?

Comment: Did you check the file case?  'Widgets' instead of 'widgets' can mess stuff up.

Comment: I would remove `$widget_view = '../widgets/'.$subdir.'views/'.$view.EXT;` as it seems to be totally redundant. Why would you want to remove APPPATH if it is proven that the file exists? Maybe you meant to use `if ( ! file_exists(...)) {` ?

Comment: @Brendan Ya, I don't know why that was there either. I am fairly certain that the problem is with the app path between the local and staging servers. When local, the file_exists() returns true, on the staging it returns false and doesn't run. Not entirely sure how to give it the correct path however. I'll edit my question to show what I need to have

Comment: What is your local server and what is your remote server? Linux? Mac? Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up just needing to `subdir = strtolower($subdir);`

Thanks for the help everyone

Answer (score 0):

If it's a staging server, go into the php.ini file and set

```
error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
display_errors = On
```

This will output whatever errors it finds so you can debug it.